# Use autocomplete_fields with Proxy model

Tags: django

I want to implement [autocomplete_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) feature but it doesn't work. I assume it happens because of Proxy model.
So I have Customer Proxy model and PromoCode model. PromoCode has FK to Customer model. And I need to have search field for customers in PromoCode change form. Here are models and admin classes:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # bunch of fields

class Customer(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['email',]


admin.site.register(Customer, CustomerAdmin)



class PromoCode(TimeStampedModel):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)


class PromoCodeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ('customer',)


admin.site.register(PromoCode, PromoCodeAdmin)
```

This code gives error:

> : (admin.E039) An admin for model "User" has to be registered to be referenced by PromoCodeAdmin.autocomplete_fields.

But I can't change model in customer field to Customer, becase when I run migration it breaks with following error:

> ValueError: The field coupons.PromoCode.customer was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.customer', but app 'users' doesn't provide model 'customer'

Also I can't register User as admin class, because I don't need it to be registered. I register Customer model.

What can I do to solve such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible (see: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30666). I got around this by registering the User admin, but making it redirect to my custom admin model. I also removed all of the actions on the user admin:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

admin.site.unregister(User)


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    preserve_filters = False

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super().get_actions(request)
        if "delete_selected" in actions:
            del actions["delete_selected"]
        return actions

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
    def changelist_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("admin:core_domainuser_changelist"))
```